# Swift disable tab bar item with function

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I have an item in my tab bar that shouldn't be enabled until certain conditions are met. I can disable that item in `viewDidLoad()` from my subclassed `UITabBarController`, but I'm having trouble creating a function that I can call when needed. Below is what I have so far - for reasons I don't understand, my tab bar item array is always nil! (Unless its initialized in `viewDidLoad()` where it works fine.)

```
func setTabState(whichTab: Int) {
    let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBar.items

    if let barItems = arrayOfTabBarItems {
        if barItems.count > 0 {
            let tabBarItem = barItems[whichTab]
            tabBarItem.isEnabled = !tabBarItem.isEnabled
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a combination of Rohit Makwana's answer and some experimentation:

1. In `viewDidLoad()` of my CustomTabBarViewController I used Rohit's
   answer to set the initial state of the tab bar items. I still don't understand why using `DispatchQueue` is necessary, but one thing at a time.
2. In a separate view controller I adopted the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and set
   `tabBar?.delegate = self`.
3. Finally, I created a property observer on a variable that gets set to true when certain conditions are met:

---

```
var allButtonsPressed = false {
   didSet {
      if let items = tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
         items[1].isEnabled = allButtonsPressed
      }
   }
}
```

And it works! When allButtonsPressed is true, the tab bar item is instantly enabled. When it's false - disabled. Plus one to Rohit for helping me get to the solution. Now, off to learn more about DispatchQueue...

Answer (score 2):

Please put below code where you want to disable tabbar item in your **UITabbarController** class

```
//Here Disable 0 Tabbar item

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let items = self.tabBar.items!
    if items.count > 0 {
         items[0].isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works great from viewDidLoad but not in a function. self.tabBar.items is nil unless its called in viewDidLoad.