# How to disable UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a Tab that extends the `UITabBarController` and three tabs. How can disable a tab from opening by condition?

```
class Tab: UITabBarController {

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        if(item.tag == 1) // dont open tab  ????
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift disable tab bar item with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617250/swift-disable-tab-bar-item-with-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
class Tab: UITabBarController , UITabBarControllerDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.delegate = self
    }
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true / false // according to vc type 
     }
}
```

Comment: do I need overide?

Comment: no just conform to the delegate `UITabBarControllerDelegate`  inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I dont understand you :(

Comment: Thx. You are right. For some reason I was not able to inherit from UITabBarControllerDelegate